# mysql and webservers loadbalancing

Tags: load-balancing

I have 2 webservers and 3 mysql servers and 2 loadbalancing ip from ovh ، one for loadbalance webservers and other for mysql servers .

how can I connect webservers and mysql servers together? what should I import in webservers and mysql configuration files?

thank you

Comment: You asked this question yesterday. Little has changed.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you don't know what to do but we can't really help you because you don't provide sufficient details. We would need to know lots more information about how your application architecture, the MySQL architecture ... This sort of stuff really isn't suitable for Q&A, questions should be specific and answerable. http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning

Comment: I have installed lemp on my webservers and I have Installed  GlusterFS software for webservers replication. I use " ovh loadbalancing IP" To loadbalance my webservers.
 
Also  I have install Percona Xtradb cluster on my mysql servers for replicate mysql servers. and I use the second " ovh loadbalancing IP" To loadbalance my mysqlservers.
Explanation: OVH loadbalancing IP that OVH datacenter provides is just used to direct  the traffics to the backend servers. And we have a graphical panel that we have added our backend servers and we do not have root access to this IP.

Comment: NOTE: Already I had 1 mysql server and I had connected webservers and mysql server succesfully by this method:
on webservers  configuration file I have applied these changes: 
wp-config.php
def define('DB_USER', 'wordpressuser');
define('DB_USER', 'wordpressuser');
define('DB_HOST', 'database_server_ip');
AND ON MYSQL SERVER I HAD IMPORTED THESE COMMANDS:
GRANT SELECT,DELETE,INSERT,UPDATE ON wordpress.* TO 'wordpressuser'@'web_server_ip';
ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO 'wordpressuser'@'web_server_ip';
GRANT FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
On mysql configuration file:
bind-address        = your_database_IP